# How to draw an object freehand on an image and move it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, package

[Free hand drawing on an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NueL6.jpg)

I want to draw freehand object on an image and also move it. Now I am using **flutter painter** package from flutter, with it I can only draw an object but I cannot move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flutter_painter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_painter) now. The new version allows you to move every shape, plus there are some awesome new features.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Draggable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) widget to drag a widget.